# A way to pivot/stack table in SQL

Tags: sql, stack, pivot-table

I have a table like this one

```
garden_1   garden_2   garden_3
apple      grape      lime
orange     apple      kiwi
lime       kiwi       orange
```

For every unique element in the whole table, i need another column containing all these unique values.

If this value appears on the column, it should return 1, else it should return 0.

So the expected output should be:

```
fruit    garden_1   garden_2   garden_3
apple       1          1          0
orange      1          0          1
lime        1          0          1
grape       0          1          0
kiwi        0          1          1
```

In Python, I use the following to make it work:

```
gardens_new.loc[:, :] = gardens.stack().reset_index().pivot_table(index=0, columns="level_1", aggfunc="count").notna().astype(int).droplevel(0, axis=1)
```

Any ideas on how I can do the same but in SQL?

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can unpivot and aggregate.  For unpivoting, the most general method is `union all`:

```
select fruit,
       sum(garden_1) as garden_1,
       sum(garden_2) as garden_2,
       sum(garden_3) as garden_3
from ((select garden_1 as fruit, 1 as garden_1, 0 as garden_2, 0 as garden_3
       from t
      ) union all
      (select garden_2, 0 as garden_1, 1 as garden_2, 0 as garden_3
       from t
      ) union all
      (select garden_3, 0 as garden_1, 0 as garden_2, 1 as garden_3
       from t
      )
     ) g
group by fruit;
```

Answer (score 0):

Below SQL gives idea on how to achieve the result you want:

`select 'apple' fruit,  sum(case garden_1 when 'apple' then 1 else 0 end) garden_1, sum(case garden_2 when 'apple' then 1 else 0 end) garden_2, sum(case garden_3 when 'apple' then 1 else 0 end) garden_3 from tmp_1 union select 'grape' fruit,  sum(case garden_1 when 'grape' then 1 else 0 end) garden_1, sum(case garden_2 when 'grape' then 1 else 0 end) garden_2, sum(case garden_3 when 'grape' then 1 else 0 end) garden_3 from tmp_1 union select 'kiwi' fruit,  sum(case garden_1 when 'kiwi' then 1 else 0 end) garden_1, sum(case garden_2 when 'kiwi' then 1 else 0 end) garden_2, sum(case garden_3 when 'kiwi' then 1 else 0 end) garden_3 from tmp_1;`

You can change this SQL as per your requirement. Decode() can also be used instead of case statements.

Comment: Gopi, thats amazing, thank you. But do you think there is a way to get automatically all unique values in the table?
Because this was an example, my dataframe has 800+ unique values